# Converting a C function to MIPS assembly

Tags: c, assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I'm currently learning MIPS Assembly and I am attempting to convert the following C function into MIPS Assembly:

```
int count (int a[], int n, int x)
{
int res = 0;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int loc[];
for(i = 0; i != n; i++)
if(a[i] == x)
{
    res = res + 1;
    loc [j] = i;
    j = j + 1;
}
return res, loc;
}
```

I've succeeded in converting most of it, and I believe I have successfully returned res (a value of 1), though I'm uncertain about returning loc (I also get a value of 1, and I don't think that's correct). However, I am having difficulty with this program and I am unsure as to how I can ensure that loc is returning the correct value or how to even code it to do so.

Here is my Assembly code:

```
.data
a: .word 5,6,7,8,9,10
n: .word
x: .word
res: .word 0
i: .word 0
jj: .word 0
loc: .space 40

.text
main:
la $s0, a
lw $s1, res
lw $s2, x
lw $t0, i
lw $t1, jj
lw $t2, n
la $s3, loc
li $t4, 6

start:
sll $t3, $t0, 2
add $t5, $t3, $s0
lw $t4, 0($t5)

beq $t0, $t4, start
addi $t0, $t0, 1
beq $t0, $t2, exit

addi $s1, $s1, 1
sll $t7, $t1, 2
add $t6, $s3, $t7
sw $t0, 0($t6)
addi $t1, $t1, 1

exit:
li $v0, 1
add $a0, $s1, $zero
syscall

li $v0, 1
add $a1, $s3, $zero
syscall
```

Any help, pointers, or suggestions would be very much appreciated.

EDIT: I've revised my code and now receive 0 for the `res` return and "268501028" for `loc`. Not sure where this number is coming from.

```
.data
a: .word 5,6,7,8,9,10
n: .word #n
x: .word #x
res: .word 0
i: .word 0
jj: .word 0
loc: .space 40

.text
main:
la $s0, a
lw $s1, res
lw $s2, x
lw $t0, i
lw $t1, jj
lw $t2, n
la $s3, loc
li $t4, 6

start:
beq $t0, $t2, exit #for(i = 0; i != n; i++)
bne $s0, $s2, else #if(a[i] == x)
j start

else:
addi $s1, $s1, 1 #res = res + 1;
sw $t0, ($t1) #loc [j] = i;
addi $t1, $t1, 1 #j = j+1
addi $t0, $t0, 1 #Increment i

addi $s3, $s3, 4 #Setting next element for loc
addi $s0, $s0, 4 #Setting next element for a
j start

exit:
li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s1
syscall

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $s3
syscall
```

Comment: `int loc[];` in the C-code makes no sense.

Comment: `return res, loc;` is, well, purely *technically* it is valid C - but it serves no clear purpose. What is that line supposed to do?

Comment: @RadLexus In MIPS asm, even with standard convention, you can return _two_ values (in `v0` and `v1`). With internal conventions, any fnc can put as many "return" values into as many registers as one chooses. The C here, is more like pseudo code for the proposed asm

Comment: @EOF From the loop in the body [and the `loc` in the asm] we can infer that `loc` is `int loc[n]`. The C is like pseudo code for the asm. Another typo mistake is that `array[i]` should be `a[i]`

Comment: @CraigEstey: I'd have been fine if the question had declared this as pseudocode, but it explicitly claims this is a C function. Which it is not. Also, the assembly version doesn't represent the `count()`-function, but `main()` with `count()` inlined, which is not making the comparison any easier

Comment: I'm analyzing the code. I've found 5 asm bugs so far. When I'm done, I'll post an answer. Is the pseudo code correct [except for typos]? The `a` _might_ match in multiple places. How to handle? Or, stop loop on first match?

Comment: So, you're interested in _just_ the index value [in `a`] of the _first_ match?!?! So, this implies that the `loc` array is largely superfluous??? (i.e. code for it can be eliminated). To me, having `loc` only makes sense if you want to collect the indexes of _all_ matches in `a`. You can have it either way [as you desire], but both the pseudo code and the asm build up the `loc` array with all values. In lieu of guidance, during exit, I would have printed `j` and then looped and printed all `loc` values, which makes the code slightly more complex

Comment: In asm, `x` is `x: .word` instead of `x: .word someval`, so it won't match anything in `a` at present. Likewise with `n`. I realize you're modeling a function, but what test values would you like?

Comment: It is [considered] very bad practice/form on SO to eliminate the code you posted originally. It makes any comments or answers previously provided nonsensical as they no longer have the context of the original. It also changed your question from one that was well formed into something so vague that it probably would have been closed. Therefore, I've rolled it back.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, there were a few bugs. I've annotated the source and added "BUG:" to hightlight them. I then created a cleaned up and corrected version

---

Here's your original code--no bug fixes, just annotations [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
# int
# count(int a[], int n, int x)
# {
#   int res = 0;
#   int i = 0;
#   int j = 0;
#   int loc[n];
#
#   for (i = 0; i != n; i++) {
#       if (a[i] == x) {
#           res = res + 1;
#           loc[j] = i;
#           j = j + 1;
#       }
#   }
#
#   return res, loc;
# }

    .data
a:          .word       5,6,7,8,9,10
n:          .word
x:          .word
res:        .word       0
i:          .word       0
jj:         .word       0
loc:        .space      40
nl:         .asciiz     "\n"

    .text

    .globl  main

main:
    la      $s0,a
    lw      $s1,res
    lw      $s2,x
    lw      $t0,i
    lw      $t1,jj
    lw      $t2,n
    la      $s3,loc
    li      $t4,6                   # BUG: extraneous (gets trashed below)

start:
    sll     $t3,$t0,2               # get i << 2
    add     $t5,$t3,$s0             # get &a[i]
    lw      $t4,0($t5)              # fetch it

    # BUG: we're comparing a[i] against i but we want to compare against x
    # _and_ we want to flip the sense of the branch
    beq     $t0,$t4,start           # is it a match? if yes, loop

    addi    $t0,$t0,1               # increment i
    beq     $t0,$t2,exit            # i == n? if no, loop. if yes, exit

    # BUG: the indexing here is wrong
    addi    $s1,$s1,1               # j += 1
    sll     $t7,$t1,2               # get jj << j
    add     $t6,$s3,$t7             # &loc[jj << j] (BUG: we want &loc[j])
    sw      $t0,0($t6)              # set it to i
    addi    $t1,$t1,1               # jj += 1

    # BUG: we should loop here and _not_ fall through

exit:
    # print j (with newline)
    li      $v0,1
    add     $a0,$s1,$zero
    syscall
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,nl
    syscall

    # print _address_ of loc[0]
    # BUG: if we care to print anything, we should print the _values_ of the
    # whole array
    li      $v0,1
    # BUG: this should be a0 and _not_ a1
    ###add      $a1,$s3,$zero
    add     $a0,$s3,$zero
    syscall
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,nl
    syscall

    li      $v0,10                  # exit program
    syscall
```

---

Here's the cleaned up and corrected version. I had to do a bit of restructuring and simplification to make it work, so it may seem a bit "alien" at first. However, I tried to retain your register usage where possible.

I also increased the size of the `a` array and added a user prompt for the `x` value:

```
# int
# count(int a[], int n, int x)
# {
#   int i = 0;
#   int j = 0;
#   int loc[n];
#
#   for (i = 0; i != n; i++) {
#       if (a[i] == x) {
#           loc[j] = i;
#           j += 1;
#       }
#   }
#
#   return j, loc;
# }

    .data
a:          .word       5,6,7,8,9,10
    .word   5,6,7,8,9,10
    .word   5,6,7,8,9,10
    .word   5,6,7,8,9,10
    .word   5,6,7,8,9,10

ae:

loc:        .space      1000

prompt:     .asciiz     "Enter x value: "
msgnl:      .asciiz     "\n"
msgj:       .asciiz     "j: "
msgloc:     .asciiz     "loc: "

    .text

# main -- main program
#
# RETURNS [sort of as this is a main program]:
#   s1 -- j value (count of elements in "loc")
#   loc -- filled in indexes into "a" array of matches to x
#
# registers:
#   s0 -- a (base address of "a" array)
#   t2 -- n (number of elements in "a" array)
#
#   s2 -- x (value to match)
#   t0 -- i (current index into "a" array)
#   s3 -- loc (base address of "loc" array)
#   s1 -- j (current index into "loc" array)
#
#   t6 -- quick temporary [reusable]
#   t7 -- used in array offset/index calculations [reusable]
    .globl  main
main:
    # prompt for x value
    li      $v0,4                   # syscall: print string
    la      $a0,prompt
    syscall

    # read in x value
    li      $v0,5                   # syscall: read integer
    syscall
    move    $s2,$v0

    # get address of "a" array and compute length
    la      $s0,a                   # get &a[0]
    la      $t2,ae                  # get address of &a[n]
    sub     $t2,$t2,$s0             # get number of bytes in a
    srl     $t2,$t2,2               # get number of words in a (i.e. n)

    li      $t0,0                   # i = 0
    li      $s1,0                   # j = 0
    la      $s3,loc                 # base address of loc array

# main matching loop
loop:
    sll     $t7,$t0,2               # get i << 2
    add     $t7,$t7,$s0             # get &a[i]
    lw      $t6,0($t7)              # fetch from it
    bne     $t6,$s2,next            # a[i] == x? if no, advance to next element

    # add new "i" value to loc array
    sll     $t7,$s1,2               # get j << 2
    add     $t7,$s3,$t7             # &loc[j << 2]
    sw      $t0,0($t7)              # store i into loc
    addi    $s1,$s1,1               # j += 1

next:
    addi    $t0,$t0,1               # i += 1
    blt     $t0,$t2,loop            # i < n? if yes, loop (or, we're done)

# done with calculation/fill loop
done:
    la      $s6,msgj                # get prefix string
    move    $s7,$s1                 # get j
    jal     prtnum                  # pretty print the number

    blez    $s1,exit                # bug out if _no_ values in loc

    # prepare to print all values of loc
    la      $t6,loc                 # base address of "loc"
    li      $t7,0                   # initial index

# loop and print all values of loc
prtlocloop:
    la      $s6,msgloc              # prefix string
    lw      $s7,($t6)               # get loc[...]
    jal     prtnum                  # pretty print the number

    add     $t6,$t6,4               # increment address
    add     $t7,$t7,1               # increment index
    blt     $t7,$s1,prtlocloop      # done? if no, loop

exit:
    li      $v0,10                  # exit program
    syscall

# prtnum -- print a number with a prefix string on a single line
#
# arguments:
#   s6 -- prefix string
#   s7 -- value to print
#
# registers:
#   v0 -- syscall number [trashed]
#   a0 -- syscall argument [trashed]
prtnum:
    li      $v0,4                   # syscall: print string
    move    $a0,$s6                 # string to print
    syscall

    li      $v0,1                   # syscall: print integer
    move    $a0,$s7                 # value to print
    syscall

    li      $v0,4                   # syscall: print string
    la      $a0,msgnl
    syscall

    jr      $ra                     # return
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> What exactly is the difference between `print` and `prtnum`?

`print` is the label for the top of the loop that prints the values in `loc`. `prtnum` is subroutine/function that does the printing of a *single* number.

I added `prtnum` to demonstrate the use of a function and to avoid needless replication of some code.

> Can they not be properly merged?

Sure, with some caveats. I did a slight/cosmetic edit to try to make things clearer. In particular, I renamed `print:` to `prtlocloop:` to try and make its role clearer.

The `syscall(1)` for "print integer" just prints the integer but does *not* add any whitespace or newline to separate them (i.e. it's *exactly* like `printf("%d",a0)`). So, we need *something*.

Originally, I just had the `syscall(print_integer)`. With that, we get one *"very long"* number. Then, I added `syscall(4)` to print a newline. This was fine except the output was a bit confusing as to which value was `j` and which were the `loc` values.

(1) So, I added the "prefix" string. So, that became three syscalls for each number.

(2) This was used in *two* places: To print `j` *and* to print the `loc` values.

Same code in two or more places. That's the standard criterion for "split out code to function" in *any* language. It's a design/style choice [so there is no absolute answer].

So, with (1) and (2), I moved it to the `prtnum` function. Actually, I wrote the `prtnum` function *first* because I already knew the structure, and added the prefix argument after the output "looked ugly" [to me].

When I first coded it, I used `"j: "` for `j` and used a `" "` prefix for `loc`. It still looked a little funky. So, I changed the prefix to `"loc: "` to be consistent.

Could it be inlined? Sure. But, in addition to printing the number itself, we still have to add a separater. So, we need *two* syscalls per number to do it.

The separater could be a space if we want to put all numbers on the same output line. Fine for short vectors. This would require a slight change to the code as it exists now and we'd have to add a final output of newline to close the line. For longer arrays [that might not fit on a single line], one per line is [probably] tidier.

We only had to print `j` and `loc`. If the problem stated that we had to print `a`, then `j`, and then `loc`, I would have gone the other way.

I would have changed `prtlocloop` into another function (e.g. `prtarray`), that would loop on the given array and call `prtnum` for each element.

The first step was getting the calculation loop correct. The second was the printing. But, sometimes, they have to be done together. (i.e.) How can you debug something that you can't see?

So, with calculation correct, you are free to recode the output printing in any way you choose. The `prtnum` was just *my* way. But, it is by *no* means the only way.

---

Beyond the basic mechanics of working with the asm instructions, the choices are just like in any other language [notably C]. Comment well, choose the simplest and most effective way to architect/split the code, use descriptive variable names, etc. Comments should show "intent", the "what/why". The asm instructions are the "how".

*Side note:* Some OPs have had serious difficulty understanding how `sll` [which you *already* understand] works. They just didn't "get" the fact that a left shift by 2 was like a multiply by 4 and converts an index value into byte/address offset. So, you may already be ahead of the game ...

Yesterday, I gave an answer for a mips question where I went the other way and recommended inlining two functions. The problem was to calculate `sin(x)` using a Taylor series expansion [summation of terms] of the form: `x**(2n)/factorial(2n-1)`.

With inlining, it was possible to reuse partial results from the previous term in the series *without* having to recalculate each term from scratch. This would not have been [conveniently] possible with multiple functions.

I didn't write the mips code, but I wrote the C/pseudo-code: [mips program to calculate sin(x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36378346/mips-program-to-calculate-sinx/36382163#36382163) The resulting mips code would [probably] have been simpler and would definitely run faster.